# Как подключится к БД Oracle используя имя сервиса (service name) вместо SID?

Tags: java, база-данных, oracle, jdbc, connection

Есть Java приложение, которое подключается к БД используя имя хоста, порт и SID. Вот так:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.dbhost1.mydomain.ca:1521:XYZ
```

Где `XYZ` это SID.

Теперь, надо подлключиться к другой БД не используя SID, а вместо него, с именем сервиса (*service name*).

Попробовал, но оно так не работает:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.dbhost2.mydomain.ca:1522:ABC
```

ABC - имя сервиса другой БД.

Что я делаю не так?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4832056/6571020) от [@Jim Tough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346112/jim-tough)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/4832056/6571020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример подключючения к БД Oracle:

```java
static void open() {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.example.com:1521/orcl", 
                                         "login", "password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: А где вы взяли этот пример?

Comment: Да уже и не вспомнить..но помню что это был какой-то курс с SQLite.. но я переделал на Оракл, так как в нём работаю.. а к чему такой вопрос?

Comment: Вы проверяли его, он рабочий? Просто ип странный, HPE принадлежит.

Comment: Рабочий, просто я поменял цифры на случайные.. ну и пароль, логин.. не указывать же :)

Comment: вот так ни думал, ни гадал в Hewlett Packard попал

Comment: Как после правки пойдёт?

Answer (score 3):

Как указанно в [следующей подглаве официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-EF07727C-50AB-4DCE-8EDC-57F0927FF61A):

> **8.2.4 Thin-style Service Name Syntax**
>
> Thin-style service names are supported only by the JDBC Thin driver. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> @//host_name:port_number/service_name
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> jdbc:oracle:thin:HR/hr@//localhost:5221/orcl
> ```

Поэтому, попробуйте так:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.dbhost2.mydomain.ca:1522/ABCD
```

Однако, если надо указать другие специфичные характеристики соединения, то лучше воспользоваться *TNSNAMES стилем*, то есть форматом принятым для tnsnames.ora файла (см. [Oracle Net connection descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-6F729E4D-064B-4FD9-AE92-1BD44B8BE5EF)). Например, для распределённого соединения:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(
    address=(host=oracle.dbhost2.mydomain.ca)(protocol=tcp)(port=1522))(
    connect_data=(service_name=ABCD)(server=SHARED)
    ))
```

PS (*прим. авт.*) Синтаксис с указанием SID больше не документирован и не рекомендуется к применению.

<sub>Использовались следующие ответы: [1 ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832116/6571020) [@Bert F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11296/bert-f), [2 ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047081/6571020) [@Jim Tough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346112/jim-tough).</sub>

Comment: Прошу прощения за занудство (не я условия придумывал), но по атрибуции SO требуются прямые ссылки на всех авторов, а они здесь отсутствуют (ссылки на ответы это не ссылки на авторов)

Comment: @andreymal Думаю это всё таки бюракратическое излишество. Тем более это микс оригинальных ответов, где в результате обсуждения остановились на следующем -- я как автор ответа сам решаю, вообще указывать что-то или нет.

Comment: ну смотрите, о возможном штрафе за возможное нарушение лицензии Creative Commons я предупредил)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Подумаю, почитаю ещё раз обсуждение, возможно поправлю.